# Are questions about sports betting, spreads, and odds on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I can see where questions in general about how spreads are determined, what they mean, and other functionality questions (especially specialty bets) being on topic.

But I see a snake pit of questions like what is/was/will be the spread for the NC-Kansas matchup.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, asking what the spreads are seems like it falls under the category of questions that don't add value to this site - considering the knowledge isn't very useful or meaningful once the game is over.

**How spreads are determined and what terms related to betting are seem OK to me.**

Comment: I agree completely. This is probably good for the FAQ...

Comment: Wouldn't knowing the odds of a game be a method of determining the relative strength of the teams involved? To me, that seems like a historical statistic, which is very much on topic.