# Area51 proposal Sports Betting

Tags: discussion, on-topic, area51

There exists area51 proposal [Sports Betting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55086/sports-betting). I am mentioning it here for several reasons:

- There is probably an interlap between between users of this site and of the users interesting in the proposed sites about Sports Betting. So I want to make more people aware of that proposal.
- I would like to know also whether questions from that proposal should be asked here in the case proposal is deleted. And even independently of it, whether questions on sports betting would be more suited here.

It seems that questions about sport betting are on-topic on this site: [Are questions about sports betting, spreads, and odds on topic?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/are-questions-about-sports-betting-spreads-and-odds-on-topic)
There exists also a tag [betting](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betting) for such questions. (So far it contains two questions.)

The proposal at area51 has not receive too much interest, it has so far only 4 followers. It is possible that it will be deleted. (Inactive proposals that do not receive any activity for one month may be deleted, according to [area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).)

Sports site has, at the moment, 2.1 questions per day according to [statistics at area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports). So if the questions from the proposed site on Sports Betting are asked here instead, it might help Sports in fulfilling requirements for graduating from beta by attracting new users and getting more questions. Of course, it would be only useful in the case that this does not bring questions to which community around this site are opposed. (Of course, to some extent, this could be solved by [ignoring tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do), if there are users who have no interest in such questions.)

I'll list here example questions from the proposal (to get an idea about the kind of the questions which might be asked there - but keep in mind that Sports Betting proposal is still in definition phase):

- What are the pros and cons of level stakes betting?
- Under what assumptions is Kelly staking 'optimal'?
- What are some good bookmaker comparison sites?
- Why do odds offered by the bookmakers tend to change rapidly during the last few minutes before the start of the game?
- How do odds comparison sites get the data with the odds for the events at various bookmakers?
- Why some bookmakers do not offer multiple bets (accumulator bets)?
- How is potential profit from an arbitrage bet (a.k.a. surebet) calculated?

Comment: "What are some good bookmaker comparison sites?" would be a source request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, Sports SE is interdisciplinary in nature. Therefore, all questions on all levels of sports could be asked.

In even shorter terms, sports betting is on-topic here.